# Weavescope on Microk8s doesn't recognize containers

Tags: kubernetes, containers, orchestration

I'm running a Microk8s single-node cluster and just installed Weavescope, however it doesn't recognize any containers running. I can see my pods and services though fine, however each pod simply states "0 containers" underneath.

logs from the weavescope agent and app pods indicate that something is very wrong, but I'm not adept enough with Kubernetes to know how to deal with the errors.

Logs from Weavescope agent:

```
microk8s.kubectl logs -n weave weave-scope-cluster-agent-7944c858c9-bszjw
time="2020-05-23T14:56:10Z" level=info msg="publishing to: weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local:80"
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.378586 Basic authentication disabled
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.439179 command line args: --mode=probe --probe-only=true --probe.http.listen=:4041 --probe.kubernetes.role=cluster --probe.publish.interval=4.5s --probe.spy.interval=2s weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local:80
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.439215 probe starting, version 1.13.1, ID 6336ff46bcd86913
<probe> ERRO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.439261 Error getting docker bridge ip: route ip+net: no such network interface
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.439487 kubernetes: targeting api server https://10.152.183.1:443
<probe> ERRO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.440206 plugins: problem loading: no such file or directory
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.444345 Profiling data being exported to :4041
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.444355 go tool pprof http://:4041/debug/pprof/{profile,heap,block}
<probe> WARN: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.444505 Error collecting weave status, backing off 10s: Get http://127.0.0.1:6784/report: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused. If you are not running Weave Net, you may wish to suppress this warning by launching scope with the `--weave=false` option.
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.506596 volumesnapshotdatas are not supported by this Kubernetes version
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:10.506950 volumesnapshots are not supported by this Kubernetes version
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.559811 Control connection to weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local starting
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:14.948382 Publish loop for weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local starting
<probe> WARN: 2020/05/23 14:56:20.447578 Error collecting weave status, backing off 20s: Get http://127.0.0.1:6784/report: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused. If you are not running Weave Net, you may wish to suppress this warning by launching scope with the `--weave=false` option.
<probe> WARN: 2020/05/23 14:56:40.451421 Error collecting weave status, backing off 40s: Get http://127.0.0.1:6784/report: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused. If you are not running Weave Net, you may wish to suppress this warning by launching scope with the `--weave=false` option.
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 15:19:12.825869 Pipe pipe-7287306037502507515 connection to weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local starting
<probe> INFO: 2020/05/23 15:19:16.509232 Pipe pipe-7287306037502507515 connection to weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local exiting
```

logs from Weavescope app:

```
microk8s.kubectl logs -n weave weave-scope-app-bc7444d59-csxjd 
<app> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.221084 app starting, version 1.13.1, ID 5e3953d1209f7147
<app> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.221114 command line args: --mode=app
<app> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.275231 Basic authentication disabled
<app> INFO: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.290717 listening on :4040
<app> WARN: 2020/05/23 14:56:11.340182 Error updating weaveDNS, backing off 20s: Error running weave ps: exit status 1: "Link not found\n". If you are not running Weave Net, you may wish to suppress this warning by launching scope with the `--weave=false` option.
<app> WARN: 2020/05/23 14:56:31.457702 Error updating weaveDNS, backing off 40s: Error running weave ps: exit status 1: "Link not found\n". If you are not running Weave Net, you may wish to suppress this warning by launching scope with the `--weave=false` option.
<app> ERRO: 2020/05/23 15:19:16.504169 Error copying to pipe pipe-7287306037502507515 (1) websocket: io: read/write on closed pipe
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` and describe how you install the weavescope? Did you follow this guide: https://www.weave.works/docs/scope/latest/installing/#kubernetes-local-clone

Comment: @KFC_ Thank you for answering. I followed that exact tutorial yes, as well as tried with the files on the github repo. It worked fine in my testing environment in Minikube, but not in Microk8s.

I no longer have access to the cluster as it was a school project that has now ended, so I no longer need help figuring it out. Thanks for the answer though.